# complete and correct directions for getting Google OAuth to return an access_token and refresh_token

Tags: google-oauth

I am looking to write a simple "Hello world" application using Google OAuth 2.0, however I have tried all 10 of the first 10 Google hits for "Google OAuth 2.0 tutorial", and for each of them, I followed all of the steps exactly as they were written, but none of them worked.  In all of the tutorials, I get as far as submitting a POST request to https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token using the values for "code", "client_id", "client_secret", "grant_type" and "redirect_uri" as specified exactly in the tutorials, which is supposed to obtain an access_token and a refresh_token if the directions are correct. But then when I submit the request I get the response:

error   "invalid_grant"
error_description   "Bad Request"

Some of the tutorials have screen captures from Google's UI which are out of date, so it may be that Google made a subtle change which invalidated the old directions.

Rather than copying and pasting the directions from each of the tutorials, so we can go over each one with a fine-toothed comb to figure out what went wrong, it seems more straightforward to just ask: Does anyone have complete and correct directions for an OAuth 2.0 "Hello world" app, to get up to the point where an access_token and a refresh_token are returned by Google?

Comment: I have written a number of articles on OAuth. Start with this article that shows you how to do Google OAuth using curl. This will help you understand the steps: https://www.jhanley.com/google-oauth-2-0-testing-with-curl-version-2/

Comment: You could follow the steps in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766912/how-do-i-authorise-an-app-web-or-installed-without-user-intervention which will get your tokens using the OAuth Playground. You can check your own http requests vs the playground to see what you are getting wrong.